# MPANDROIDCHART: How to draw X label with .setViewPortOffsets(0,0,0,0)

Tags: android, charts, mpandroidchart

I have a problem with draw X label when my chart has been set setViewPortOffsets on 0, 0, 0, 0. I know what setViewPortOffsets do, But I don't know how to set it to make only the margins disappear on left and right side. Can someone help me please?

PS: Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Can you include some of your code in your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add following lines to remove axis lines from both sides of chart:

```
chartView.getAxisLeft().setEnabled(false);
chartView.getAxisRight().setEnabled(false);
```