# How hide MPAndroidChart left and right border？

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

This is my code

```
    mLineChart.setDrawBorders(false);
    mLineChart.setBorderWidth(0);
```

i try use setDrawBorders(false)，but left and right have gray thin line，

how hide this line？

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MPANDROIDCHART: How to draw X label with .setViewPortOffsets(0,0,0,0)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47780961/mpandroidchart-how-to-draw-x-label-with-setviewportoffsets0-0-0-0)

Comment: The checked answer over there will do the job

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding :

mLineChart.getAxisLeft().setDrawAxisLine(false);
mLineChart.getAxisRight().setDrawAxisLine(false);

You can also check if this axis draw enabled or not by :

mLineChart.getAxisLeft().isDrawAxisLineEnabled(); 
mLineChart.getAxisRight().isDrawAxisLineEnabled();

Answer (score 0):

To remove left line you need to add:

```
mLineChart.getAxisLeft().setEnabled(false);
```

To remove right line you need to add:

```
mLineChart.getAxisRight().setEnabled(false);
```

Comment: Thank you! line is hide,but label hide too